# Rails custom route with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of generated links created by

```
  <% @location.exits.each do |e| %>
    <%= link_to e.name, go_to_path(e) %><br/>
  <% end %>
```

which goes to: `get 'go_to' => 'adventure#goto'` in `routes.rb`

which links back to:

```
  def goto
    current_user.location_id = params[:id]
    render 'index'
  end
```

However, when clicking on any of the links, it leads me to the url: `http://localhost:3000/go_to.2` instead of say `http://localhost:3000/go_to/2`

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix you route to:

```
get 'go_to/:id' => 'adventure#goto'
```

[`Read about routes in Rails and the-query-string`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-query-string)